# How to blend a Zend MVC login system with a responsive HTML5 login page

Tags: html, zend-framework, view

I'm slowly tackling OO and Zend Framework and their MVC process in particular.

I have an existing **Zend 1.12 MVC login page** with session,users,login,register functionality.

**Everything is build** and ready. Except of the design of views that looks **awfull**!!!

**I'm wondering how can I mix the views of Zend framework with a responsive HTML5 page
that I created.**

**Do you have in mind a demo,guide in Zf 1.12 that explains step by step how to 
make the views to support responsive design patterns??**

Again, I'm really a newbie at Zend especially in the design part of it.

Comment: This is not directly related to ZF I think. ZF works with viewscripts you can use to create a design as you like. The limits are your imagination. See also: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.scripts.html

Comment: As reading in the example view scripts can include some html elements as table,div. In my example I have also to include css,sass, media queries and some ajax calls. Where should I include all these files? Thanks for answering

Comment: CSS/SASS etc can be configured in various ways. Maybe you could start using headlink/headscript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305130/how-to-load-css-and-javascript-files-from-a-module-in-zend-framework-1 & http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headlink